# How to use .gitlab-ci.yml on gitlab.com to build from Dockerfile and copy artifact from Dockerfile to GitLab public directory?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, gitlab-ci, artifact

While I can successfully write a `.gitlab-ci.yml` on `gitlab.com` that [passes my `artifact` to `public/`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/getting_started_part_four.html),

```
image: ruby:2.3

pages:
  script:
  - bundle install
  - bundle exec jekyll build -d public
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
```

I would like `.gitlab-ci.yml` (a container (#1) based on a docker image (#2)) to instead use a `Dockerfile` to build a different image (#3) to create the `artifact` and, again, pass the `artifact` from #3 to `container#1/public/` so it is publicly accessible on the web.

```
# Dockerfile
FROM ruby:2.3
...
```

The rationale for this is that I might share the repo with a colleague who understands Dockerfiles but is not interested in using GitLab or `.gitlab-ci.yml`. So I want `.gitlab-ci.yml` to use `Dockerfile` for my purposes and my colleague can use `Dockerfile` in whatever way is most comfortable for them--`Dockerfile` is the shared, reproducible way of making the `artifact`.

It seems I can [build Docker images in GitLab CI/CD](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html), but I'm not sure I can do so on `gitlab.com` rather than self-hosted GitLab. This would then allow me to push image to a registry and use the image from the registry in a later stage (including the `artifact`). Although I'm not sure how I would extract it?

`docker build -t myimagename .` does not work in GitLab CI/CD on `gitlab.com` (unless I add in some `services` to the `.gitlab-ci.yml`?). Even if it did, how would I extract the `artifact` from the `myimagename` container into the GitLab CI/CD "container"?

Comment: so you want to export a docker image as an artifact? i am still not sure i got you

Comment: @EfratLevitan, i want `.gitlab-ci.yml` (a container(#1) based on a docker image(#2)) to use my `Dockerfile` to build a different image(#3), inside of which docker will also build the `artifact`. Then I want `.gitlab-ci.yml` to extract the `artifact` from #3 and copy it to `container#1/public/` so it is publicly accessible on the web.

Comment: can be easily completed with `docker cp` command.